# How to combine N amount of expression trees with OR/And operators

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, delegates, iqueryable

Currently I have an expression tree that represents a **MONSTOROUS** `Lambda` in the form of `Expression<Func<Project, bool>>` I did this to replace a repetitive amount of looping with `Linq`.

Here is the tip of the iceburg.

```
        return prj => !FilterCriteria.IsFilterEnabled && prj.OrganizationID != null
                      || (((FilterCriteria.OrganiazaitonId == null) || organizationIDs.Contains(prj.OrganizationID.Value))
                       || ((FilterCriteria.ActivityTypeId == null) || (act.ActivityTypeID == FilterCriteria.ActivityTypeId))
                          && ((FilterCriteria.ProductLineId == null) || (prj.ProductLineID == FilterCriteria.ProductLineId))
                          && ((FilterCriteria.ProjectTypeId == null) || (prj.ProjectTypeID == FilterCriteria.ProjectTypeId))
                          && ((FilterCriteria.ProjectId == null) || (prj.ProjectID == FilterCriteria.ProjectId))
                          && ((FilterCriteria.StartDateFrom == null) || (prj.StartDate >= FilterCriteria.StartDateFrom))
//... this goes on for about 40 more lines
```

I have grouped these `expression trees` into 6 categories and want to combine them based on a conditional statement.
Basic example

```
if(...){
        Expression<Func<Project, bool>> filterEnabled = prj => !FilterCriteria.IsFilterEnabled && prj.OrganizationID != null;
 }
 else if(...){       //combined with `OR` statement

        Expression<Func<Project, bool>> organizations = prj => organizationIDs.Contains(prj.OrganizationID.Value);
 }   
 else if (...){       //combined with `AND` statement

        var projectType = prj => (prj.ProjectTypeID == FilterCriteria.ProjectTypeId);
 }
...
```

How can I combine these into a single `expression tree?`

Comment: This shall be simple, just use `Expression.And` or `Expression.Or` calls to aggregate various expressions in the single Expression tree call

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This shall be simple, just use `Expression.And` or `Expression.Or` calls to aggregate various expressions in the single Expression tree call. Let me provide an example, if you have a `List<Expression>`, which needs to be aggreagated into Single Expression then use the following code using `And` aggregation for example, it can be any of the predicate builder:

```
    List<Expression> exptree = new List<Expression>();

    var resultEXpression = exptree.Skip(1).Aggregate(exptree.FirstOrDefault(), 
    (exp1,exp2) => Expression.And(exp1,exp2));
```

This is just a sample, there are lot of Expression builders available by default, which can help bind the expressions together based on relevant logic, it can be `Or, AndAlso, OrAssign, OrElse`

Comment: Thank you, that's actually easier than expected.

Comment: Welcome, glad it helped